# CAN-Bus shield, SD-card module & LED_BUILTIN use D13; possible collision?

Tags: communication

To my knowledge the SeeedStudio CAN-Bus shield utilizes D13, and so does the [SD-card module](http://ebay.to/2lqdrsL) I use. And also Arduino Uno's LED_BUILTIN is 13. **Am I in danger of some sort of collision here?**

I have read [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67212/how-to-avoid-sd-card-and-w1500-spi-mixup-on-the-ethernet-shield/67214#67214), but that one describes situation where both modules are on *a single shield.*

Why I am alerted: I can perform following sequence: turn the LED on, open file, write, close file, turn the LED off, no apparent problem here. But when I connect my CAN-Bus shield to merely read messages (i.e. no sending data to the shield, not on purpose) my car behaves funny as if I still somehow managed to send some rogue bytes to the shield. (Right side windows and mirror are dead, infotainment display shows dead splash screen, dashboard complains about "engine malfunction" and airbags...)

I wonder if by writing to the SD-card and possibly turning the LED on I didn't send some bytes to the shield. Do I need to somehow Select Slave?

Comment: The actual cause of the car going crazy was that I did not have GND connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are in danger of a collision, how much danger I can't say, but the potential is there.

1. You could stop using the LED on D13?
2. Could you move the pins of your SD card reader, or get a different one that allows I2C or SPI interfacing?

I guess there is nothing that can be done to the CAN bus device, but if there is it might be a good idea to move its pins.